# Snapshot testing react component which depends on inject mobx store

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mobx

I've been trying to figure out how to do simple snapshot testing for a few components that have mobx stores injected into them. Here's an example:

At the root i have a `<Provider>` wrapping the whole shebang at my final `ReactDOM.render()` in the entry point. (not shown here)

```
// component.js

...{imports}...
@inject('mystore')
@observer
export default class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Stuff</div>
    )
  }
}

// component.test.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Component from './'

it('renders a snapshot', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<Component/>).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I get a failed test because it's missing a store provided up the tree. I've tried exporting an "undecorated" component like so:

```
// in component.js
...{same as above}...

export const undecorated = Component
```

and then importing the undecorated component in my snapshot test, however this doesn't work.

Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to pass a mock of the store as a prop to your undecorated component?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass the store explicitly like so:

`const tree = renderer.create(
          <Component.wrappedComponent myStore={store}/>).toJSON();
 )`